# Страница для печати , не работает print

Tags: html, css, css3, media-queries

Всем привет , верстаю страницу для  media print , столкнулся с одной проблемой
Все хорошо , только вот есть блок , с текстом , при вставке которого , иногда print отображает весь текст , а иногда весь текст на print странице вообще не выводится , очень интересная ситуация , пока химичу думаю может у кого уже бывало такое , что подскажете ?
Спасибо
Вот код.

```
.inttour {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1% auto;
    color:blue;
    min-height:540px;
    max-height:1000px;
    width:95%;
    padding:2% 2%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:1.5;
     word-wrap:break-word;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;


}


.inttour:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2); -moz-transform: scale(1.2); -o-transform: scale(1.2); -ms-transform: scale(1.2);

}


.inttexttour1 {
font:normal 20px Times New Roman;
color:white;
margin:0 auto;
padding:4% 4%;

width:100%;


}

.tourblock {
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    margin:0 1% 0% auto;
    width:68%;
    height:100%; 
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);

    padding:0 2%;
    text-align:center;
}

<div class="tourblock">
<div class="inttexttour1">
<div class="inttour">   
 <?php $cfile = 'content/content5.txt';$cont = file_get_contents($cfile); echo $cont; ?>     

</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

При таком коде , текст в print не видно !

а при таком все показывается

```
<div class="tourblock">
<div class="inttexttour1">
<!--<div class="inttour"> -->
 <?php $cfile = 'content/content5.txt';$cont = file_get_contents($cfile); echo $cont; ?>     

<!--</div> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил , сменил название стиля , видимо этот стиль inttour используется еще где-то, и конфликтует

---

Для тех кому понадобится , проблема была в том что в `inttour` я не поставил размер шрифта , после добавления в `inttour` `font:normal 20px Times New Roman;` проблема решается , и все нормально отображается : )